# getting data from two tables for the same user?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables question and answers.

```
- questions{id,user_id,question,date}
- answers {id,q_id,user_id,answer, date}
```

I want to retrieve the questions and answers that have been inputted by the same user

```
 i.e. select all answer and all questions for ID=39 order by date DESC
```

and also after I have a query, and I'm wanting to while through the fetch array, and displaying the data, how can I distinguish whether it was a question or an answer, so I can display them correctly.

EDIT:

```
SELECT 'Q' AS
TYPE , q.question AS value, q.date
FROM questions q
WHERE q.user_id =39
UNION ALL SELECT 'A' AS
TYPE , q.question AS value, a.date
FROM answers a,questions q
WHERE a.q_id = q.id
AND
WHERE a.user_id =39
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

im sorry but im trying to get the question that has been answered rather then the answer itself. i updated the sql and the database design on top, but i keep getting an error

Comment: you can do two separate queries to separate both questions and answers.

Comment: Please post a new question, providing the query and the error details.

Comment: i have check it out on my profile, :)) sorry about that!!!

Comment: You might be better off doing a new question with examples of your data and expected results. It now looks like you need a `JOIN` not `UNION`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT 'Q' AS type,
         q.question AS value,
         q.date
    FROM QUESTION q
   WHERE q.user_id = ?
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS type,
         a.answer AS value,
         a.date
    FROM ANSWER a
   WHERE a.user_id = ?
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

`UNION` and `UNION ALL` are used to combine queries to return a single result set.  `UNION` removes duplicates; `UNION ALL` does not remove duplicates and is faster than `UNION` because of this.  But there needs to be the same number of columns in the SELECT clauses of all the SELECT statements in a UNION'd statement.  And their data types have to match at each position.

To differentiate between answers and question values, the example defined static values "A" to stand for answers, and "Q" to stand for questions.  Your application layer code can work off these to format the data as desired.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when im fetching the data using php, how can i know if its type A or Type Q thanks!!!

Comment: @pingpong: By checking the value for the row of the resultset in PHP.

Comment: thanks so basically the the word type is now actually value i.e. `FetchArray['type']` :)) +1 from me, so i check whether `FetchArray['type']` equals A or Q

Comment: @pingpong: I'm not familiar with that syntax, but if you are only interested in Answers or Questions, you should only query for what you want.  If you're displaying information for both, then minimizing the number of queries is a good idea assuming possible.

Comment: i updated the question, but i kep getting an error, sorry for the inconvienance!!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 'Q' as `type`,
       id,
       user_id,
       question as quesion_or_answer,
       `date`
FROM   questions
WHERE  user_id = 39
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' as `type`,
       id,
       user_id,
       answer as quesion_or_answer,
       `date`
FROM   answers
WHERE  user_id = 39
ORDER  BY `date`  DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be lazy and use an UNION ALL as that just concatenates two tables:

```
SELECT *, NULL as answer FROM questions WHERE ID=39
UNION ALL
SELECT *, NULL as question FROM answers WHERE ID=39
ORDER BY date DESC
```

The trick for the later differantiation is to have a null field, or some other identifier.

Answer (score -1):

As there doesn't seem to be a relation between questions and answers: Use separate queries.

Comment: Not my downvote (I tend to agree with the sentiment). This wouldn't meet the requirement that they should be ordered by date in a combined manner however.